# How to i parse elements with [CDATA] tags

Tags: nsxmlparser, cdata, rss-reader

I'm trying to pull images from my  tag using NSScanner, but my  tag has a [CDATA] block that makes my NSXLM parser ignore everything inside that tag. How can i parse the data inside my  tag, heres a sample of the rss feed , and a sample of the parser code.

```
<item>
        <title>Kendrick Lamar &amp; Lady Gaga in Chi-Town</title>
        <link>http://www.motahiphop.com/rap-pix/36-rap-pix/2346-kendrick-lamar-lady-gaga-in-chi-town</link>
        <guid isPermaLink="true">http://www.motahiphop.com/rap-pix/36-rap-pix/2346-kendrick-lamar-lady-gaga-in-chi-town</guid>
        <description><![CDATA[<p style="text-align: center;"><img src="http://www.motahiphop.com/images/lady-gaga-kendrick-lamar.jpg" width="500" alt="Kendrick Lamar with Lady Gaga at Pitchfork festival" /></p>
```

After tweeting that she was a Kendrick Lamar fan last week. Lady Gaga caught up with the Compton MC back stage at Chicago's Pitchform Music festival.

]]>
            gqwebsites@gmail.com (Super User)
            Featured
            Rap Pix
            Rap Pix
            Mon, 16 Jul 2012 13:18:45 -0400

Parser code snippet:

```
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) 
{
    elements[@"title"] = title;
    elements[@"date"] = date;
    elements[@"summary"] = summary;
    elements[@"link"] = link;
    elements[@"description"] = description;

    //NSLog(@"%@", description);

    [posts addObject:elements];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

after some research I found the answer on another post, I used this method

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCDATA:(NSData *)CDATABlock
{
    NSString *description = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:CDATABlock encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *storyImageURL = [self getFirstImageUrl:description];
    NSLog(@"%@",storyImageURL);
```

I added the NSLog at the end so you can NSLog the results and check that the data is being pulled. works like a charm